# Monodromy action induced by higher direct images.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$  be a n-dimensional complex variety and let $f:X\longrightarrow \Delta$ be a Lefschetz degeneration (f is proper, with non zero differential on $\Delta^*$ and with one ODP in the fibre $X_{0}$).

Why the the monodromy action induced by the local system $R^if_{*}\mathbb Z$ is trivial for $i<n-1$.